# Programmatically trigger CustomBuild command for a custom file of VS2019 c++ project

Tags: c#, c++, msbuild, custom-build

My VS2019 c++ project contains a custom file FileName.xyz, which I'm building using custom build command:
`MyTool.exe FileName.xyz  Output: FileName.cpp`

Now from C# project code, I want to programmatically build this C++ project using MSBuild.Execution()

```
MsBuild.Execution.BuildResult result = MsBuild.Execution.BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParams, buildRequest);
                    if (result.OverallResult == MsBuild.Execution.BuildResultCode.Success)
```

This actually creates a enc_temp_folder and copies FileName.xyz file, but as .xyz file is unknown type returns success.
this only works for 'ClCompile' type, but as my custom file FileName.xyz is defined as a CustomBuild item in .vcxproj file, it is not building. FileName.cpp is also defined as ClCompile item in vcxproj file.

### I want to change above code to trigger pre build command:
command:
`MyTool.exe FileName.xyz Output: FileName.cpp`
so that with generated FileName.cpp default build is performed.

I don't know how and what I need to change?
I've found msbuild.execution.projecttaskinstance may help, but not seen any code example.